# Why doesn't TypeScript throw an error when returning invalid properties on implicitly typed return object?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a function signature that helps the caller only return properties that exist on the associated type. I'm using a `Partial<Record<keyof...` pattern to accomplish this. If the caller explicitly sets the return type, the type safety I'm looking for is accomplished, and they see they are passing in an invalid type. But if they just return an object implicitly (which I can't control), then the function writer seems to be able to return invalid fields in the return object.

Does anyone understand why this is?

```
interface CatInfo {
  age: number;
  breed: string;
}

function expected(): Record<keyof CatInfo, CatInfo> {
  const cats: Record<keyof CatInfo, CatInfo> = {
    age: { age: 4, breed: 'oo'},
    breed: { age: 10, breed: "Persian" },
    boris: { age: 5, breed: "Maine Coon" }, // correctly errors, because boris is not in keyof CatInfo
  };
  return cats;
}

function notExpected(): Record<keyof CatInfo, CatInfo> {
  const cats = {
    age: { age: 4, breed: 'oo'},
    breed: { age: 10, breed: "Persian" },
    boris: { age: 5, breed: "Maine Coon" }, // why doesn't this throw an error?
  };
  return cats;
}

expected().age;
// ^?
```

I have this in the typescript playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJzASRDA9sgbwChlk4BzCALmRAFcBbAI2gG4TkmoIIATGgM5goocuwC+RIjDogEYYLhDIIADwAOEeXwAUAShoAlLbii8APAGsIAT1ww0GbHgA0jrDlwA+QhwRKhZAQMASMTMytbe3dnXDd0DzwfAF5fUlIKakIyShoAFjcuHn5kAHJcXFLxFw5SIr4aAhysgEYABkLuBuQAIgAFaAFgOBAe5GrazlNgUOzMmgBWTuKaHoBZOFAUVArR8bcAegPkTGQAd1w6ABteFQ0tMGQwfAEeMmVoKFNkAAtoCEKWjgdFeUxEAmQM1ouEeoGQ1jsDgSsQ44nYpG4YDoUGUwTAAgkUhkcgUSmhYAAovdtLx9GF-BEEdFkZ54k5PD5iKR-CBAniIakuel5nNcsgCpwuiVypUJulJStRa0Ogruv1BsM9nL0kxprMmiKlqqSutNiBtrsxtVkEdzj8bMheLgIAIQKVHmAflDPV8zu8VFAvlAAPyo9HITHY3EhQlENSaGn6AB0mXYtoAesGgA)

Answer (score 0):

The error in this case may be a bit misleading. The error is based on the declared variable and the expected return for the function which do not match in the type check. By declaring the type of the return and then the type of the returned object, you are informing the interpreter enough to detect the error and flag it.

In the second function, the interpreter is checking that the return meets the qualifications of CatInfo's interface but that is all and since it does meet those qualifications a runtime error wouldn't appear here, which is why if you comment out breed you will see the error pop-up, but not when commenting out boris. It's a little more apparent when looking at the JavaScript which is identical for these two functions.